# In objection how to filter based on "child" element?

Tags: javascript, inner-join, objection.js

Well in objection you can use `withGraphFetched` to help build an object structured view of a database.

Considering a mandate that belongs to a customer, one would (after defining the model correctly) call it like:

```
const mandates = await MandateModel
    .query(db)
    .withGraphFetched('_customer');
```

Which works quite well. However now I wish to select "all mandates belonging to customer XYZ". I notice it is possible to add a select to the `withGraphFetched`:

```
const mandates = await MandateModel
    .query(db)
    .withGraphFetched('_customer(isCustomer)')
    .modifiers({
        isCustomer(builder) {
            builder.where('key', custId)
        }
    });
```

However this just makes the customer field `null` when there are no customers. - However can I modify the query so it does a proper join-check? Yet does return in the correct structure?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try something like below,

```
const mandates = await MandateModel.query(db)
.withGraphJoined('_customer')
.whereIn('_customer.key', custId)
```

See this [link](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/eager-methods.html#withgraphjoined) for further reference.

Comment: Your answer doesn't resolve the issue because you changed the join behavior to`withGraphJoined` instead of `withGraphFetched`. Indeed, `_customer` is not  available with `withGraphFetched` because `_customer` is fetched from a different SQL statement.